# Displaying .properties Value in Spring JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, javabeans, spring-java-config

I'm trying to display the version of the application I'm building in Spring 4 in the footer of each jsp page. I want to read the value from a .properties file and output it to footer.jsp which will be inherited on each page.

It's not working as I wish and I'm having a tough time debugging this.

Questions: Is this the right approach? If so, any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried:

Context Configuration:

```java
@Bean(name = "applicationVersion")
public String applicationVersion() {
    return environment.getRequiredProperty("application.version"));
}
```

@javaConfig

```java
@Bean
public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new  InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

  viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
  viewResolver.setExposedContextBeanNames("applicationVersion");
  return viewResolver;
}
```

JSP:

```jsp
<span><c:out value="${applicationVersion}"/></span>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Spring` but have you tried to print something to the console before sending it to your `JSP` ? Just in case...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you looking at,just some guideline that I can help you:

Setting properties file in Java Config;

```
@Bean(name = "PropertiesFile")
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer cmsProperties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholder = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ClassPathResource[] value = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("Put your properties location here") };
    placeholder.setLocations(value);
    return placeholder;
}
```

And if u want to use the data in properties file,

Just use `@Value`

For example in properties file you have this:

```
version=1.3
```

Then to call it just use this in controller or bean:

```
@Value("${version}") String version
```

I hope its help!